# How to extend a dictionnary in a such way?

Tags: python, statistics

I've got this project about stats and I just wondered how to create a list from a dictionnary like this:

```
{1:3, 2:4} => [1,1,1,2,2,2,2]
```

Thanks you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This simple snippet should do it

```py
l = []
for k, v in d.items():
    l.extend([k] * v)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension as:

```
x = {1:3, 2:4}
res = [k for k, v in x.items() for i in range(v)]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

we can easily do this by getting the keys of the dictionary. so basically 1 and 2 is our keys and its values are the times that it required to be added to list so we will use for loop to achieve the same.

```
myDict = { 1:3, 2:4 }
myList = list()
for key in myDict.keys():
    for i in range(myDict[key]):
        myList.append(key)

print(myList)
```

In above code the first loop will get the keys and the second will iterate to the limit and append the key into the list